# How to replace each second CR LF in TXT file

Tags: notepad++

I need to replace each second CR+LF in my TXT file.
Now i have this:

```
zyxel(CR+LF)
    5640000(CR+LF)
zorro(CR+LF)
    8420000(CR+LF)
zoom(CR+LF)
    750000000(CR+LF)
```

I need to get this:

```
zyxel1  5640000(CR+LF)
zorro00 8420000(CR+LF)
zoom    750000000(CR+LF)
```

How can i do this? Thank you.

Comment: I guess `zyxel1` and `zorro00` in the desired result are typos, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Search` > `Replace` menu (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and do the following:

1. Find what:

   ```
   (\w+) *\r?\n[ \t]*(\d+)
   ```
2. Replace:

   ```
   $1\t$2
   ```
3. Select radio button "Regular Expression"
4. Then press `Replace All`

Input:

```
zyxel
    5640000
zorro
    8420000
zoom
    750000000
```

Output:

```
zyxel 5640000
zorro 8420000
zoom  750000000
```

You can test it at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/lO9tR7).